# PHP/MySQLi - Fatal error: Call to a member function mysqli_query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
require "../include/functions.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();

$Cat = addslashes($_POST["Category"]);

$v = $conn->mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");
$vrowi = mysqli_fetch_array($v, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$url = $conn->real_escape_string($vrowi['Link']);
```

Here is what i have in `functions.php`:

```
function ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase() {

     global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database, $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;

    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }


    $conn->set_charset("utf8");

    global $conn;

}
```

The variables `$dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database,` are set correctly.

When i try to execute this mysqli_query i receive the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function mysqli_query() on a non-object in <b>/fetch_category_products.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
```

Line 19 is:

```
$v = $conn->mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");
```

Can you please tell me where is my mistake and how can i fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from. (`addslashes` is not safe for this, even the documentation for `addslashes` says so)

Comment: With what i have to replace it ? `mysqli_real_escape_string` ?

Comment: @TonyStark Please consider using PDO for your database work.

Comment: So it is not safe to use `mysqli` and it is way better to use `pdo` ?

Comment: @TonyStark — Try clicking on the links in the comment.

Comment: mysqli is not unsafe. Reasons for choosing PDO over it are not connected to security.

Comment: So please tell me what i have to use instead of `addslashes` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error arises because the database connection isn't working – it literally means that the value of `$conn` isn't an object, which probably means it's either not set or set to `false` because the connection failed. Change `ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase()` so that its last line is not `global $conn;` but `return $conn;`.

Now change the way you call that function from `ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();` to be `$conn = ConnectWithMySQLiDatabase();` and I believe the problem will go away.

OP posted an update after this change, and the confusion became more clear: now they have a `MySQLi` connection, they should just use `query`, like this:

```
$v = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");
```

Comment: var_dump gives me this: http://pastebin.com/Uf7HgUwB and i still receive error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_query()` on this line `$v = $conn->mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `id`=$Cat");` Any advice ?

Comment: Thank you! The screenshot was very helpful. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now i receive this error: `<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in` on the same line.

Comment: Now everything works just fine. Thank you so much for your effort. I have just one more question about securing. Instead of using `addslashes` is it enough to use this `$conn->real_escape_string()` ?

Comment: Don't use `addslashes()`. Using `real_escape_string()` provides much more safety, but isn't a complete solution by itself. Using PDO with bound parameter + input filtering gets you what you want.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to run while loop queries. So far i tried this `$v = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE Link != ''");

 
 while($vrowi = mysql_fetch_array($v, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                  
 {
}` Do i have any mistake ?

Comment: You need to post new questions as new questions so that others can help too. That being said, at least convert your whole `mysql_fetch_array()` call to `$v->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381431/php-mysqli-trouble-running-while-loop